# Spring Hibernate : Multiple resultset mapping

Tags: spring, hibernate

I want to understand the limitations of Spring's Data repository.

While querying the database, it seems that Spring repository can only return entities, or a collection of same type, like string/int etc. It makes sense because the Spring Repository is a function and a function can only return one result.

So what if I need to execute a complexe sql by using @Query annotation, and expect more than one result? like a collection of entityies and a number.

I don't think it is possible with Spring Repository, so if i'm wrong, please correct me.

And more importantly, how could I do that by using spring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible that I know of for the Repository to work with queries, but the Repository is used by a Spring ServiceImpl anyway and you can Inject an `EntityManager` into the serviceImpl and use that. For example see [Getting started with Spring Data JPA](https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/10/getting-started-with-spring-data-jpa):

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

TypedQuery query = em.createQuery("select a from Account a where a.customer = ?1", Account.class);
query.setParameter(1, customer);
return query.getResultList();
```